# spring-boot-actuator Management Port Requires servlet-api for spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

When building an application against spring-boot 2.0.0.M4 using the netty reactive server through these starter dependencies:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux')
```

I try to set `management.port=9000` and get this message on startup:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.ManagementContextAutoConfiguration$DifferentManagementContextConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.ManagementContextFactory' that could not be found.
  - Bean method 'reactiveWebChildContextFactory' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.servlet.Servlet'
  - Bean method 'servletWebChildContextFactory' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.servlet.Servlet'


Action:

Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.ManagementContextFactory' in your configuration.
```

When I add an explicit dependency on `javax.servlet-api`:

```
compile('javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0')
```

the spring-boot app comes up without problem and the `management.port` value is honored.

Is this expected behavior for a reactive web application with spring-boot or an issue with the dependencies for `reactiveWebChildContextFactory` that should be raised as an issue on the repository? Adding the servlet-api provides no functional difference to my spring context, so it seems like this shouldn't be a requirement for the child context factory.

Comment: I haven't checked out the details yet, but this [commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/a274c78fa0a3b5e0f29a12924247eabbe4005b86) in 2.0.0.M4 provides actuator endpoints in a webflux app. I don't think `management.port` and `javax.servlet-api` are required.

Comment: See this [blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2017/08/22/introducing-actuator-endpoints-in-spring-boot-2-0) for more details on my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks ken, I need some way to be able to separate the actuator port from the application port on a reactive webapp. I'm running in a Kubernetes environment and automate a number of tasks based on the 'actuator' service port binding. This means I need `management.port` or something similar to its functionality, so that actuator is running on a different port than the rest of the app.

Comment: See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10589

Comment: It looks like this was resolved by this PR: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/10590. Thanks!